# How to cancel hiredis blocking operation

Tags: c++, blocking, hiredis

Having a blocking subscription running like below halts the program at `redisGetReply` (source: [hiredis#pipelining](https://github.com/redis/hiredis#pipelining))

```
void subscribe (std::string& key, Subscriber* subscriber)
{
    void* reply = redisCommand (redis, "SUBSCRIBE %s", key.c_str ());
    freeReplyObject (reply);
    while (redisGetReply (redis, &reply) == REDIS_OK)
    {
        subscriber -> notify ();
        freeReplyObject (reply);
    }
}
```

I thought by invoking `redisFree` (thru signal handling) the socket would be closed and `redisGetReply` returned, as mentioned at [hiredis#cleaning-up](https://github.com/redis/hiredis#cleaning-up), instead it throws a memory access violation.

Comment: I am not sure why this question is voted down so much. I have the same question since I don't want to re-implement all my redis code to use the async API when a simple disconnect request might be possible with blocking operations too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, nevermind. I managed to simply close the file descriptor which is being used by hiredis by invoking...

```
close (redis -> fd);
```

... and `redisGetReply` returns properly.

Alternatively, one could send a `QUIT` command and the blocking subscription returns.

Comment: AFAIK hiredis blocking API is not thread safe and you are not supposed to send commands like QUIT from another thread (or signal handler). Closing the socket/file descriptor would work, but uses internal OS dependant implementation details. For OS independent approach redisReconnect() does disconnect too, but that might not be thread safe - a bit like sending QUIT. It would be nice to have proper disconnect() that is documented and implemented in thread safe manner (OSes support it anyway, shouldn't be too hard).